# Serviceaccount does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission

Tags: google-bigquery

Permission given to service account is "owner" and "bigquery admin".

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
            'projectId' => 'project-xxx',
        ]);

      $query = "SELECT * FROM `project-xxxx.analytics_xxx.events_xxx` where event_name='first_open' LIMIT 100";

        $jobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
        $queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($jobConfig);
        print_r($queryResults);
```

when I try to execute above code its show below error:

```
{ "error": 
{ "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "accessDenied", 
  "message": "Access Denied: Project project-xxxx: The user 
  projectbigquery@project-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have 
  bigquery.jobs.create permission in project project-xxxx." } ],
}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After creating new service account with same permission as per previous account, its working. I don't know whats wrong with previous account. May be some issue from service account.

Comment: If the service account was deleted and recreated it with the same name it could lead to unexpected behavior. Most proably that's why creating a new service account solved the issue. Check this https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts

Comment: Read the answer again, I have mentioned that I have given same permission I have not mentioned anything about name.

Comment: For my case... I created the service account with no permissions. Got access denied. I added the permissions later (after I realized I forgot to). Once I deleted the account and recreated, it worked. I did use the same service account name.

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify the credentials of the service account as a parameter of the [`BigQueryClient` constructor](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-bigquery/v1.5.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=__construct).

You can do it with the `keyFilePath` parameter:

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
            'projectId' => 'project-xxx',
            'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/file.json'   
        ]);
```

Also, check with this command that you granted the permissions to the service account:

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy yourProjectID`

**EDIT:**

Let's take a different approach creating a service account and granting permissions to it from scratch.

1. Create new service account:

   `gcloud iam service-accounts create [NAME]`
2. Grant the permissions:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member "serviceAccount:[NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/bigquery.admin"
```

3. Create credentials file:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create [FILE_NAME].json --iam-account [NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

4. Add the path of this file to the `BigQueryClient` contructor and run your code.

Comment: Where do I need to fire this command, at google cloud shell ?

Comment: Are you creating the constructor specifying the `keyFilePath` parameter to the credentials json file? Also check that these credentials are up-to-date in the `IAM & admin > Service Accounts` Google Cloud Console tab.

Comment: @Krunal I have edited my answer with fully detailed steps.