# GCP Cloud Storage file push by python using service account json file

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have written simple python program as per Google documentation. It throws me an error saying given account does not have access. Tried different combinations but didn't work.

I have cross checked the given access by supplying to java program and gsutil. Both these places I am able to access the bucket and upload file. Issue with the python program. Kindly show some light on this issue.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:/Users/AWS/python/sit.json'
    ,scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials,project='proj-sit')  
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('b-sit')
blob = bucket.blob('myfile')
blob.upload_from_string('New contents!. This is test.')
```

and i have received below error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AWS\python\mypgm.py", line 21, in <module>
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('pearson-gcss-sit') # pearson-gcss-sit  pearson-bbi-dev global-integration-nonprod
  File "D:\Development_Avecto\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage\client.py", line 227, in get_bucket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "D:\Development_Avecto\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage\_helpers.py", line 106, in reload
    method="GET", path=self.path, query_params=query_params, _target_object=self
  File "D:\Development_Avecto\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.py", line 319, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/b-sit?projection=noAcl: someid-sit@someinfo-sit.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to b-sit.
[Finished in 10.6s]
```

Note : I can see role as '*storage.objectAdmin*' in console.cloud.google.com.

For more information, I can upload the files by using below java program.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(connectionKeyPath))
                                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
                        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
                        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("some-sit", "cloudDirectory/file.zip");
                        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("application/zip").build();
                        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, fileContent);
```

I got the root cause of the issue.

Root cause : My bucket has access of 'roles/storage.objectAdmin' which does not have access to 'storage.buckets.get'. Hence I get the above error in the line where i have get_bucket function. This I have found in the google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).

All the sample codes in the documentation has get_bucket function to upload the files. My questions how can we upload the files to bucket without this access (storage.buckets.get)? Because we uploaded to the same bucket by Java without this access.

Can you show some light on this ? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the line to get the bucket in my code and added below line. Below line done a trick to me. Hence I can upload the file with the access of 'roles/storage.objectAdmin'

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket('b-sit')
```

Answer (score 4):

The service account you are using does not have the proper [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions).

You can solve this issue by granting at least the `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role at bucket or project level.

> The `roles/storage.objectAdmin` [role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles):
>
> Grants full control over objects, including listing, creating, viewing, and deleting objects.

To [grant it at bucket level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add) run:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:someid-sit@someinfo-sit.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectAdmin gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

To [grant it at project level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#project-add) run:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding yourProject --member serviceAccount:someid-sit@someinfo-sit.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/storage.objectAdmin
```

**EDIT**:

You need to pass the credentials to the [`storage_client`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html#module-google.cloud.storage.client):

`storage_client = storage.Client('proj-sit', credentials=credentials)`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I can able to push the files using java program. Still do i need to give access ?

Comment: @Simbu The error you are getting is clearly pointing to a permissions error. Can you edit the question with the output of the commands ```gcloud projects get-iam-policy yourProject --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:yourServiceAccount"``` and `gsutil iam get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

Comment: I don't have access to execute gcloud command. So I have tried in python program which i have updated in my question. could you please share some insight on this. I got only service account json from the google cloud team.

Comment: @Simbu If you don't have access to manage the project roles you need to ask whoever provided you with the serviceAccount credentials to grant it with the permissions mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @IIompalles - I have verified by login to google console. I can see the role - storage.objectAdmin given to 'someid-sit@someinfo-sit.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

Comment: @Simbu, did you previously delete the service account and create it with the same name? This can lead to [unexpected behaviour](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts). Also could you take the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54985653/7757976) to create a new service account and try again?

Comment: @IIompalles - this account is not deleted and recreated. Let me try the given answer.

Comment: Tried the given answer as well. no luck :(

Comment: @Simbu, you need to pass the credentials in the Client constructor. I have updated my answer. If this does not work please grant the role at bucket-level as it is explained as well in my answer.